# how to change root widget from popup in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

if i add a button in root and push the button to open popup, the popup widget is not the child of root widget.
So,i cannot change the property of root by find the parent of the popup.
How to deal with it?

Comment: Try using `App.get_running_app().root`.

Answer (score 0):

the parent of the popup is WindowSDL.
you can find root widget in the children of WindowSDL.